# how to transform oject with array inside into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i receive this entrie from form html POST request

```js
const obj = {
  'experience[0].companyName': 'test',
  'experience[0].postName': 'testt',
  'experience[0].startDate': '2022-01-04',
  'experience[0].endDate': '',
  'experience[0].description': '',
  'experience[1].companyName': 'stet',
  'experience[1].postName': 'esttest',
  'experience[1].startDate': '',
  'experience[1].endDate': '',
  'experience[1].description': 'stetset'
}
```

and i search to transform into simple array of object like this

```js
const experience = [
  {
    companyName: 'test',
    postName: 'testt',
    startDate: '2022-01-04',
    endDate: '',
    description: ''
  },
  {
    companyName: 'stet',
    postName: 'esttest',
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    description: 'stetset'
  }
]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please provide what you tried, SO has a good guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. (make sure to read the “Help others reproduce the problem” section)

Comment: srx i redit my question

Comment: Looks like you haven't tried anything yourself. Try to iterate through the "obj" object and store it in your "experience" object. It should be simple enough. If you still face issues then post your tried code here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a function to extract data, I have tried it:

```
const obj = {
  'experience[0].companyName': 'test',
  'experience[0].postName': 'testt',
  'experience[0].startDate': '2022-01-04',
  'experience[0].endDate': '',
  'experience[0].description': '',
  'experience[1].companyName': 'stet',
  'experience[1].postName': 'esttest',
  'experience[1].startDate': '',
  'experience[1].endDate': '',
  'experience[1].description': 'stetset'
}


let finalArr = []
for (key in obj) {
  // code block to be executed
  let finalValue = obj[key];
  let attributeArr = key.split(".");
  let numberPattern = /\d+/g;

  //get the index of the data
  let index = attributeArr[0].match( numberPattern )
  index = Number(index)
  
  let thisObj = finalArr[index]
  if(!thisObj){
    thisObj = finalArr[index] = {}
    
  }

  thisObj[attributeArr[1]] = finalValue

}


console.log(finalArr)
```

Comment: if it helps, please accept it as answer as it may help others for similar question

Answer (score 0):

In this example I make use of an imitatively invoked function expression to "evaluate" a string (like `experience[0].companyName = "test"`) that inserts properties into an object.

The try/catch will test if an object is there (like `experience[0]`). If not, it troughs an error, and in the catch I push the empty object that is needed into the empty array.

```js
const obj = {
  'experience[0].companyName': 'test',
  'experience[0].postName': 'testt',
  'experience[0].startDate': '2022-01-04',
  'experience[0].endDate': '',
  'experience[0].description': '',
  'experience[1].companyName': 'stet',
  'experience[1].postName': 'esttest',
  'experience[1].startDate': '',
  'experience[1].endDate': '',
  'experience[1].description': 'stetset'
};

var experience = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  try {
    Function(`return ${key}`)();
  } catch (err) {
    experience.push({});
  }
  Function(`return ${key} = "${obj[key]}"`)();
});

console.log(experience);
```